# Use Elliptic curve cryptography to encrypt string in java

Tags: java, encryption, elliptic-curve

I want to use JDK 1.7 alone to implement ECC so that I can encrypt string, however, when I searched all over the Internet, most of pages talked about bouncy castles. I also checked Java documentation, but it only provides ECC signature and no encryption methods are offered.

Is there any way I can learn how to implement such an encryption algorithm with only java itself?

Comment: Sure, you can probably implement ElGamal and ECIES based on ECDH in JDK 7 only using the Standard Library.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Could you please tell me where I can find some code example like this? I have searched in Gtihub but most of them used external librarys.

Comment: I don't think anybody is doing it, because BouncyCastle and other libraries are readily available. If you're talking about ECDH, then any search engine is your friend, but not necessarily GitHub